# Is there a way to only allow a site visitor to trigger a goal once?

Tags: experience-analytics, rules-engine, goals

I am diving into Sitecore rules for Goals.  We have a goal with points, "Download White Paper".  However I only want that goal to trigger once for a user in a current or subsequent visits.

I have found this oddly worded rule for a goal:

> where the specific goal was triggered during a past or current
>   interaction and when the number of elapsed days compares to number and
>   when the past number of interactions compares to number and the custom
>   data compares to value

Can I use this rule to accomplish what I want to do?

Comment: Not sure about goals, but if you could switch to using outcome instead it already has this feature out of the box.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate question - please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314735/register-a-sitecore-goal-only-once

Comment: Could you be more specific how you want to use this information? Why only once?

Comment: The feature on an outcome has been removed in Sitecore 9 btw...